# summing sub query in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

so this query works for a specific userID.

https://postimg.org/image/iq4jmvblj/

```
SELECT customer_profile.userID, 
    (SELECT sum(deposit.amountSuccessfulDeposits) 
        FROM customer_profile
        INNER JOIN deposit
            on deposit.userID = customer_profile.userID
        WHERE customer_profile.userID = 2022765) as depositSum,
    (SELECT sum(withdrawal.amountWithdrawal)
        FROM customer_profile
        INNER JOIN withdrawal
            on withdrawal.userID = customer_profile.userID
        WHERE customer_profile.userID = 2022765) as Wsum,
    customer_profile.amountGamingPlayerBalancecurrent as PlayerBalance,
    (sum(deposit.amountSuccessfulDeposits)*0.09) as Psum
```

FROM customer_profile
INNER JOIN deposit
    on deposit.userID = customer_profile.userID
INNER JOIN withdrawal
    on withdrawal.userID = customer_profile.userID
WHERE customer_profile.userID = 2022765
    AND withdrawal.withdrawalType = 'Total'

However, when I run for the entire data warehourse (same query, but eliminate the "customer_profile.userID = 2022765" lines), it sums the entire database for the depositSum value for each userID instead of calculating the depositSum value for each individual userID.

I can't use the group by within the subquery because it would return multiple columns.

https://postimg.org/image/3vfy8p20n/

```
    SELECT customer_profile.userID, 
        (SELECT sum(deposit.amountSuccessfulDeposits)
            FROM customer_profile
            INNER JOIN deposit
                    on deposit.userID = customer_profile.userID
            WHERE customer_profile.userID = deposit.userID) as depositSum,      
        (SELECT sum(withdrawal.amountWithdrawal)
            FROM customer_profile
            INNER JOIN withdrawal
                    on withdrawal.userID = customer_profile.userID
            WHERE customer_profile.userID = withdrawal.userID) as Wsum,
     customer_profile.amountGamingPlayerBalancecurrent as PlayerBalance,
        (sum(deposit.amountSuccessfulDeposits)*0.09) as Psum         
FROM customer_profile 
INNER JOIN deposit  on deposit.userID = customer_profile.userID 
INNER JOIN withdrawal   on withdrawal.userID = customer_profile.userID 
WHERE withdrawal.withdrawalType = 'Total' GROUP BY customer_profile.userID
```

help?

Comment: Please edit your question and copy the queries into the question as text.

Comment: You need to correlate those subqueries.  No need for the `join` in those subqueries.  Instead you should alias the `customer_profile` table in the outer query and use that as `where` criteria in the subqueries...

Comment: how do i copy and paste the text without it looking like an unformatted mess?

Comment: nevermind. i figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option using `correlated subqueries` instead:

```
select cp.userid,
       (select sum(amountsuccessfuldeposits)
        from deposit d
        where cp.userid = d.userid) as depositSum,
       (select sum(amountwithdrawal)
        from withdrawal w
        where withdrawaltype = 'Total' and cp.userid = w.userid) as wsum
from customer_profile cp
```